# Pass array from javascript to page in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a page in wordpress, that uses an jquery and ajax to get information from an external api.  The form sends the array generated in javascript back to the same page with another variable that the php in the page uses to determine which page to display.  Outside of wordpress, the code works fine.  Inside Wordpress the first portion runs, but then instead of loading the same page again it goes to a search page and says nothing found.

The url on the output is:

```
http://kltools.net/?s=&post_type%5B%5D=portfolio&post_type%5B%5D=post&post_type%5B%5D=page
```

Which seems odd considering I'm using post not get.

The javascript that generates the array and submits the form:

```
function submitchans(){
  for (var i=0;i<chans.length;i++)
  { var newHidInp = document.createElement('input');
        newHidInp.type  = 'hidden';
        newHidInp.name  = 'chans[]';
        newHidInp.value = chans[i];
    form.appendChild(newHidInp);
  }
}
function livearray(input){
    if (input != null) {
    chans.push(input);
    }
    if (Y === cSize){
        submitchans();
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }

}
```

Previously the array was outArray[] instead of chans[], I changed it thinking that may be triggering the result, but no luck.

This is the PHP portion of the code:

```
<?php
$page_to_load = $_POST[view];
switch($page_to_load) {
    case '':
        echo "<script src=\"../scripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js\"></script>";
        echo "<script type=\"application/javascript\" src=\"../scripts/raid.js\"></script>";
        echo "<font size=\"+3\" color=\"#FFFFFF\">Who should I host?<br>Please wait while channel is selected<br></font>";
        echo "<font size=\"+2\">";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "<img src=\"../_images/ajax_loader_blue_350.gif\">";
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "database";
        $chanarray[] = null;
        $offline = 0;

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT `TwitchNames` FROM TK_Members WHERE Validated='1' AND RaidMe='1'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
             // output data of each row
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  array_push($chanarray, $row['TwitchNames']);
            }
        } else {
           echo "0 results";
        }
        array_splice($chanarray, 0, 1);
        $conn->close();
        echo "<script type=\"application/javascript\">";
        echo "var channels = ". json_encode($chanarray); 
        echo "</script>";
        echo "</font>";
        echo "<form id=\"form\" method=\"post\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"view\" value=\"page2\">";
        echo "</form>";
    break;

    case 'page2':
        echo "<font size=\"+3\" color=\"#FFFFFF\">Who should I host?<br>";
        echo "Your channel to host is:<br></font>";
        echo "<font size=\"+2\">";
        echo "<br><br>";
        $chans[] = null;
        $test = $_POST['chans'];
        foreach ($test as $chan) {
            $temparray = array(rand(),$chan);
            array_push($chans, $temparray);
        }
        array_splice($chans,0,1);
        sort($chans);
        echo "<a href=\"https://twitch.tv/".$chans[0][1]."\" target=\"_blank\">".$chans[0][1]."</a>";
        echo "<br><br><br>";
        echo "<a href=\"whoslive.htm\" target=\"_parent\">See All Live Channels</a>";
        echo "</font>";
    break;
}
?>
```

After working with what blokeish has suggested I've modified the javascript file working out where the problem is.

The new javascript file is:

```
// JavaScript Document

var chans = ["test1","test2","test3"];



function submitchans(){
  for (var i=0;i<chans.length;i++)
  { var newHidInp = document.createElement('input');
        newHidInp.type  = 'hidden';
        newHidInp.name  = 'chans[]';
        newHidInp.value = chans[i];
     document.getElementById('chansform').appendChild(newHidInp);
  }
}
jQuery(function ($) {
        submitchans();
        document.getElementById('chansform').submit();

});
```

Using only the javascript clicking submit, it passes to the next page.  When adding in the array pass is when it fails.  This is the page log that is returning during the execution.  !!--CORRECTION--!! there was a typo in the code, after correcting ID to Id the code is working as intended.

[image: Array Errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*document.forms[0].submit()* is likely submitting the wp search form as that could be the first form in the DOM. I see "http://kltools.net/?**s=**" in the URL where "s" is the search term.

Using *document.getElementById('idOfForm').submit()* should get you around that problem if there are multiple forms in a page and you cant be sure of its index.

Comment: I've tried your idea of changing the submit to `document.getElementByID('chansform').submit();` and updating the form id to match.  The result is still the same.  It goes to a search result page saying nothing is found.

Comment: What's the action URL of the 'chansform'? Can you post the link to the form page?

Comment: Thanks but many errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined
    at submitchans (raid.js:13)

Comment: Yes, the form isn't defined in the javascript, it's defined in the php so it won't know the form until the form is presented by the php.

Comment: form.appendChild(newHidInp) on line 13 throwing error because the variable/object "form" is not defined. You have to do something like document.getElementByID('chansform').appendChild(newHidInp);